# How to create Multiple online store in magento

Tags: magento

How to implement multiple online store in magento.I have tried to implement multiple online store in my magento site by using the below links but its not working.
[Multiple online store](http://magento-rohan.blogspot.in/2012/10/magento-managing-multiple-website-stores.html) and [Multiple website store](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/) .

As mentioned in this link i cant find any line as Mage::run() in my index.php file.

Comment: When i am trying to open that multistore the url redirects to error page

Comment: Did you resolved or still the issue persists ?

Comment: still it remains same in my index page i cant find any exact code like this Mage::run()

Comment: I am getting the 404 page not found error.My entire site get collapsed after tried to implement multiple store.i was not able to open my main store itself

Comment: As i have refer i found that we need to create add-on domain for each store.Is it possible to do in localhost wamp server.if so how?